# Beinhaltet "Feuer anlegen" auch das Anzünden des Feuers?

Tags: word-usage, phrase

Ich suche nach dem deutschen Ausdruck fürs Vorbereiten eines (Lager)Feuers, also das Herrichten von Holz, das dann nur noch angezündet werden muss. "Feuer anlegen" enthält bereits das Anzünden, oder? Was wäre der korrekte Ausdruck für das Herrichten/Vorbereiten des Feuers?

Comment: Nur zur Klarstellung: "Feuer anlegen" selbst ist durchaus idiomatisch, aber hat keinen Bezug zur Sammeln/Aufschichten des Holzes, sondern nur zum Anzünden.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ich finde, du sagst es schon selbst am besten.

> Ein Feuer herrichten

dürfte alle Vorbereitungen einschließen.

Answer (score 4):

Wie wäre es mit "Feuerstelle vorbereiten"? Das hatten wir oft als Aufgabe bei den Pfadfindern, ist also definitiv eine Phrase die genutzt wird.

Comment: Ist denn damit auch das Platzieren von Holz (man macht ja zum Beispiel in der Mitte gerne so eine Pyramide, die man besonders leicht anzünden kann) gemeint? "Feuerstelle" klingt ja so, also würde man erst mal nur Platz fürs Feuer machen, oder verstehe ich das zu wörtlich?

Comment: Es ist definitiv metonymisch, aber ich würde sagen ja, es schließt den gesamten Vorgang mit ein: putzen, flach machen, evtl. unterlegen bei nassem Grund, bereitstellen von Anzündmaterial, aufschlichten eines Holzstoßes. (Wobei ich, auch als Pfadfinder, sagen muss, dass unter nicht optimalen Bedingungen das Pyramidenfeuer, in das man nur mehr ein Streichholz halten muss, illusorisch ist. Viel besser ist es, Zunder anzuzünden und kontinuierlich größere Stücke nachzulegen.)